# Merging two DataFrames without losing information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames like here:

```
df1 =

sent  token   token2
 0     a        b
 0     a        c
 0     b        d
 1     g        h
 1     h        k
 1     h        i
 1     g        i
 1     g        k


df2 =

sent  token   token2  rel
 0     a        b      A
 1     g        h      B
 1     k        g      C
```

Now I want to merge those two DataFrames into one which should look like this:

```
df_new =

sent  token   token2   rel
 0     a        b       A
 0     a        c      NaN
 0     b        d      NaN    
 1     g        h       B
 1     h        k      NaN
 1     h        i      NaN
 1     g        i      NaN
 1     g        k       C
```

However merging the DataFrames like this

`df_new = df1.merge(df2, on=["sent","token","token2"], how="left")`

I get the output I want except the `["rel"]` token is wrong

```
df_new =

sent  token   token2   rel
 0     a        b       A
 0     a        c      NaN
 0     b        d      NaN    
 1     g        h       B
 1     h        k      NaN
 1     h        i      NaN
 1     g        i      NaN
 1     g        k      NaN
```

This is due to the order of the token in `df1`. Since the value in `["rel"]` depends on `["token1"] -> ["token2"]` it can't apply its value when the order is reversed. Is there any way to do this in the merging process without creating a new version of `df1` ?

Comment: No, you'll have to do some sort of manipulation on df1 or df2 to get the results you desire, there is not a parameter in merge that will let your change merge keys.

Comment: Yes, I had to improve my `df1` to include all possible combinations of token and token2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I had to include all possible combinations of `token` and `token2` in the first DataFrame since the result of `rel` is dependent on the correct order of the two value. Meaning my desired outcome was wrong to begin with.
I had to delete this line in the creation of `df1`:

```
df1[['token','token2']]=np.sort(df1[['token','token2']],1)
```

So I get the desired version of df1 for this task.

```
df1 =

sent  token   token2
 0     a        b
 0     a        c
 0     a        d
 0     b        a
 0     b        c
 0     b        d
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `np.sort`

```
df2[['token','token2']]=np.sort(df2[['token','token2']].values,axis = 1)
df1.merge(df2, on=["sent","token","token2"], how="left")
Out[398]: 
   sent token token2  rel
0     0     a      b    A
1     0     a      c  NaN
2     0     b      d  NaN
3     1     g      h    B
4     1     h      k  NaN
5     1     h      i  NaN
6     1     g      i  NaN
7     1     g      k    C
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with my initial post. While this solution does work for this case it also doesn't work for all the other cases where the order was right. It's not dependent on alphabetical order.

Comment: @ThelMi where is other case ? You should include them in your question man